# spark-submit not exiting even after process finishes successfully

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have written a simple application and it is running fine but when I am submitting the code via spark-submit even after close() is called the spark-submit session is not finishing and I need to kill the PID.

Below is the code snippet

```
object FaultApp {

  case class Person(name: String, age: Long)

  def main(args: Array[String]):Unit = {  

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .config("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
  .appName("parjobs")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)
 // create the implicit ExecutionContext based on our thread pool
implicit val xc = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(pool)

import Function._

val caseClass = Seq(Person("X", 32)
                      ,Person("Y", 37)
                      ,Person("Z", 37)
                      ,Person("A", 6)
                   )


val caseClassDS = caseClass.toDF()

val taskA = write_first(caseClassDS)

Await.result(Future.sequence(Seq(taskA)), Duration(1, MINUTES))

spark.stop()

println("After Spark Stop command")  
  }

}

object Function {
  def write_first (ds : DataFrame)(implicit xc: ExecutionContext)  = Future {
   Thread.sleep(10000)
   ds.write.format("orc").mode("overwrite")
     .option("compression", "zlib")
     .saveAsTable("save_1")
  }
}
```

I am submitting the job using the below command

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client fault_application-assembly-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --executor-memory 1G --executor-cores 2 --driver-memory 1G
```

Below are the last few lines from the log

```
18/04/18 15:15:20 INFO SchedulerExtensionServices: Stopping 
SchedulerExtensionServices
(serviceOption=None,
 services=List(),
 started=false)
18/04/18 15:15:20 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Stopped
18/04/18 15:15:20 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: 
  MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
18/04/18 15:15:20 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
18/04/18 15:15:20 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
18/04/18 15:15:20 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
18/04/18 15:15:20 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
18/04/18 15:15:20 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
After Spark Stop command
```

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do here 
Await.result(Future.sequence(Seq(taskA)), Duration(1, MINUTES))
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're creating an execution context with a threadpool, so your program won't shut down until that is also shutdown.

After `spark.stop()`, add

```
xc.shutdown()
println("After shutdown.")
```

In alternative, instead of creating a new execution context for your futures, you could just use the global one:

```
 implicit val executor =  scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global
```